# Animation Not Smooth On Galaxy Note

Tags: android, animation, view, galaxy

I have an application that contain some simple animations, just hiding Views when user touch a button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:toYDelta="-200"
    android:duration="250" />
</set>
```

I have tested my application on Samsung Galaxy S (1 GHz, 480x800), Samsung Galaxy Ace (800 MHz, 320x480), Sony Ericson Xperia X8 (600 MHz, 320x480) and an AVD (240x320), the animation looks fine on all of the devices.

However, when I test it on two units of Samsung Galaxy Note (dual core 1.4 GHz, 800x1280), the animation looks bad, it is not smooth. I have no idea why because this device is supposed to be the most powerful among the devices I tested and it can run other applications without any problem, only the animation of my applications looks bad. Why is it so?

Would appreciate if you could give me some clue on the root cause. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, I still have no idea why did it happen on Gingerbread Galaxy Note, I suspect hardware acceleration for UI was not enabled to conserve battery. Anyway, since the device has been officially updated with Ice Cream Sandwich, I guess there is no purpose to further look into it as `hardwareAccelerated="true"` will work on new and /or updated devices.

dtmilano's answer was not selected because at the time of answer, Galaxy Note was on Gingerbread.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that you have **hardware acceleration** enabled for your application.
In you manifest add

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

The only drawback could be that your application will consume more memory.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but according to [Android official website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html), hardwareAccelerated only works for devices with API level 11 (3.0 Honeycomb) or above. The Galaxy Note I tried are running on 2.3 Gingerbread. I tried it anyway and as expected, it didn't work.